# BeautifulSoup scraping wunderground data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, screen-scraping

I'm learning how to scrape data using the book "Visualize This" by Nathan Yau. I'm trying to scrape Wunderground for the year 2009, but I'm getting this error. It's saying it is out of range, but I don't get why.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "get-weather-data.py", line 24, in <module>
     dayTemp = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"nobr"})[5].span.string
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Create/open a file called wunder.txt (which will be a comma-delimited file)
f = open('wunder-data.txt', 'w')

# Iterate through months and day
for m in range(1, 13):
  for d in range(1, 32):

  # Check if already gone through month
  if (m == 2 and d > 28):
    break
  elif (m in [4, 6, 9, 11] and d > 30):
    break

  # Open wunderground.com url
  url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2009/" + str(m) + "/" + str(d) + "/DailyHistory.html"
  page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

  # Get temperature from page
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
  # dayTemp = soup.body.nobr.b.string
  dayTemp = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"nobr"})[5].span.string

  # Format month for timestamp
  if len(str(m)) < 2:
    mStamp = '0' + str(m)
  else:
    mStamp = str(m)

  # Format day for timestamp
  if len(str(d)) < 2:
    dStamp = '0' + str(d)
  else:
    dStamp = str(d)

  # Build timestamp
  timestamp = '2009' + mStamp + dStamp

  # Write timestamp and temperature to file
  f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n')

# Done getting data! Close file.
f.close()
```

Comment: Where is this `nobr` class coming from, which temperature do you want to extract?

Answer (score 3):

There are no elements with `class="nobr"` on a day weather history page.

If you want to get the *actual mean temperature*, here is how I would locate it:

```
dayTemp = soup.find("span", text="Mean Temperature").parent.find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip=True)
```

If printed with `m` and `d`, the output would be:

```
1 1 14°F
1 2 28°F
1 3 19°F
...
```